# rails carrierwave default_url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, default, carrierwave

i don't think im understanding this correctly, but how do i give users a default image?

```
   def default_url
      "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
   end
```

i have an image called 'default.png' inside my images/fallback directory. ive seen online also  people change the version_name to something like 'tiny' but that doesn't seem to work for me either. what's going on? what exactly is the version name?

i tried something like

```
   def default_url
      "/images/fallback/default.png"
   end
```

but that doesn't work either. what am i misunderstanding?
thanks!

edit:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
   def default_url
      ???????
   end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
   version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_fill => [80, 80]
   end

end





class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
     :remember_me, :image, :remote_image_url, :image_cache

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example you have uploader like this:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [280, 280]
  end

  version :small_thumb, :from_version => :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [20, 20]
  end

   def default_url
      "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
   end
end
```

`/images/fallback/default.png` stands for original image, for `small_thumb` version path is `/images/fallback/small_thumb_default.png`, and so on.

If you want the path where images actually saves after processing, you need `store_dir`

```
  def store_dir
    'public/my/upload/directory'
  end
```

Comment: which one do i reference then exactly? im still kinda confused. i thought the default_url was where i reference the default image, not anywhere from the thumbs. am i supposed to put the default image elsewhere first?

im using the images normally from my version :thumb, and tried thumb_path but i dont think thats correct..

Comment: @Crystal default image uses when requested image couldn't be find. For example you delete small_thumb, than carrierwave gonna to display small_thumb_default.png. You can avoid using default images if you are sure that all images will be always in place.

Comment: hmmm, its still not quite working. im having a sign-up registration form, and when the user signs up i want the default image to be displayed at least until the user changes it. after i sign up, i check my database and my 'image' column is still null. if i manually change my profile pic to an image, then that 'image' column gets data. is there a way to basically have the 'default.png' data in the 'image' column when the user first signs up?

Comment: @Crystal post your model and uploader please

Comment: `"/images/fallback/" + [version_name,"default.png"].compact.join('_')` use this as default url, and add two images `app/assets/images/fallback/default.png`, `app/assets/images/fallback/thumb_default.png` Make sure that they accessible via browser url, i.e. paths aren't messed up via assets.

Comment: oh i didnt know you responded. i used that exact default url and it still doesn't work. i made both of those images and i can access both of them through the browser. however, when a user signs up, the image column of the db is still null

Comment: @Crystal Yes, it's should be null, but when you will display image from null column, carrierwave will try to display image from default_url

Comment: hmmm do you have any other suggestions or ideas? carrierwave doesn't seem to display the image from default_url

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the asset pipeline then you do not need to include "images" in your file path because the `image_tag` will automatically route to the `assets/images` folder and then look for the file name there. So the path you need in the `default_url` method is whatever comes after the images folder.  In my case it was just default.png because I had no sub folders in the images folder.

```
    def default_url
       'default.png'
    end
```